# Add a tab semantic UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, semantic-ui

I want to add a tab with semantic UI.
I have 2 tabs that are already existing (for testing):

```
  <div class="textarea">
      <div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
        <a class="item active" data-tab="first">First</a>
        <a class="item" data-tab="second">Second</a>
      </div>
      <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment active" data-tab="first">
        <textarea></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="second">
        <textarea></textarea>
      </div>        
    </div>
```

and my js code when I want to add a tab

```
let new_tab = () => {

              let tab = document.createElement('a')
              tab.className += 'item'
              tab.innerText = language
              var att = document.createAttribute("data-tab")
              att.value = language;
              tab.setAttributeNode(att);

              let div = document.createElement('div')
              let _textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
              div.appendChild(_textarea)
              div.className += 'ui bottom attached tab segment'
              att = document.createAttribute("data-tab")
              att.value = language;
              div.setAttributeNode(att);

              textarea.childNodes[1].appendChild(tab)
              textarea.appendChild(div)
        }

    $('.menu .item').tab();
```

The elemt is well added, but when I click on the tab, nothing happens.
I searched for 'reload' the tab, and then allow the new tab but I didn t find what I was looking for...
Can anyone tell me if such a thing exists?